# Links to network drives with C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, clipboard

As part of an application, im trying to resolve network drive paths as a hyperlink and copy it to the clipboard by using Qt/C++. So that a user can copy the link into an email or a word document.

Example:
//server/test --> should apear as a link in an email

I tried to use HTML but word and outlook do not recognize the string as a hyperlink. How do i have to encode the path string to get a link within word or outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Proper hyperlink for **your local network** have to be generated using [file://](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) protocol.

Your example:

```
file://server/sharename/fileorpath
```